# Plot only one half of FFT in matlab

Tags: matlab, fft

I want to show the amplitude and frequency in one plot. It only shows both halves. (length of my sound is 1 second!)

```
fs_orig = 44100;
nbits = 16;
N=44100; %amount of samples???
[x1,fs_orig,nbits]=wavread('Mysong.wav');
[B2,A2] = butter(4,[5875 6500]/(fs_orig/2),'bandpass');

dataIn = x1; %your music
dataOut2 = filter(B2, A2, dataIn);
data_pow2 = dataOut2.^2;

X_mags2 = abs(fft(data_pow2));

bin_vals = [0 : N-1];
fax_Hz = bin_vals*fs_orig/N;
N_2 = ceil(N/2);

plot(fax_Hz(1:N_2), 20*log10(X_mags2(1:N_2)))
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Magnitude (dB)');
```

Now it still shows both side, any one knows why?

Comment: `X_mags2` is undefined in your code.  I'm assuming that is storing the magnitude of your frequency decomposition.  Can you please update your code to show us that declaration?  Consider cleaning up your code as well to eliminate some of the extraneous parts.  I can see a few lines that don't add to your problem.

Comment: Edited it, using rms is the same as using dataOut^2 right?

Comment: No it isn't unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're not getting the right results is because you are confusing the total number of points that the FFT produces in comparison to your sampling frequency, which is 44.1 kHz.

The default number of points the FFT computes with amounts to the length of your input signal.  Therefore, if your signal `data_pow2` had 128 points, then the output will also have 128 points.  You can manually specify how many points in the FFT you want by specifying an additional parameter to it:

```
B = fft(A, N);
```

Here, `N` would be the number of points you want the FFT to have.  Not specifying this will assume that you want the total number of points to be the length of the input.    As such, what you actually need to do is change `N` to be the length of your signal instead.  Therefore, you need to do this:

```
[x1,fs_orig,nbits]=wavread('Mysong.wav');
N = numel(x1);
```

Declare `N` **after** you do `wavread`.  As such, if you say your signal is 1 second, then that should mean that the total number of elements should be 44100.  Verify that `N` is equal to 44100 when you read in your signal with `wavread`.

Comment: I cut 1 second out a track.

Comment: @user4390280 - What is your sampling frequency?  Is it `44100`?  Because if you are getting `88200` for the length of your signal, that means you are cutting out two seconds of data, not one if `numel(x1) = 88200` and your sampling frequency is 44.1 kHz

Comment: Probably that would be my mistake, is there any way to calculate the sampling frequency based on the amount of samples?

Comment: @user4390280 - Nope.  The number of samples you get is independent of the sampling frequency.  BTW, your call to `wavread` already gives you the sampling frequency.  It's the second output parameter of `wavread`, which you have as `fs_orig`.  However, I am telling you that you simply need to take the length of your signal and divide it by 2.  You are calling `fft` in the default way, which gives you the total number of points to be the length of the signal.  If you want to plot half of the spectrum, simply take the length and divide it by 2.  I don't know how you're not getting it to work.

Comment: Or did I had a mistake with my recording? Because i should have 44100 samples/second 16 bits per sample and need to select one second of it.

Comment: @user4390280 - Simply check `fs_orig` and `numel(x1)`.  If they both equal the same number, that means you have recorded one second worth of audio.

Comment: I fixed it with this, 

y=signal_orig(:,1);
y=y*32768;
y=round(y);

Now they are the same.

Comment: @user4390280 - That is some serious voodoo code.  What is `y`?  It isn't defined anywhere in your code.... well either way, I'm glad you fixed it... even though the errors were certainly on your end.

Comment: Have one question, how can i change the range of my magnitude? Now the range is 0 - 300 but want to change it from 100 - 300?

Comment: y = x1; sorry for that